# PK of Many to Many table is mapped as FK to anything Many to Many table in code first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

These are my tables: CFFPart, Disp, CFFPartDisp, Expert, CFFpartDispExpert,
CFFPartDisp has many - many relationship between CFFPart & Disp.

```
ToTable("Discipline", "dbr");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("DispID");
        Property(t => t.Text).HasColumnName("DisPName");

        HasMany(t => t.CFFParts).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("DisPID").MapRightKey("CFFPartID").ToTable("CFFPartDisP", "dbr"));
```

CFFpartDisPExpert has many - many relationship between Expert & CFFpartDisP
How do i write mapping for this in code first?

Comment: Could you write more details? May be show database diagram. And what is your problem?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov - I am creating a combined table (CFFpartDisp) from two tables (CFFPart and Disp) in Code First.  The database currently uses the combined table's ID (Primary Key) to establish a relationship to Expert. I dont know how to map the combined table ID with expert ID using CodeFirst?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must expose `CFFPartDisp` as an entity class in your model. You cannot use it as a link table between `CFFPart` and `Disp` with the Fluent mapping in your question. The relationship between `CFFPart` and `Disp` isn't a many-to-many relationship (in the strict EF sense). Instead you must create two one-to-many relationships with `CFFPartDisp` as intermediate entity. Then you can link your relationship between `CFFPartDisp` and `Expert` to this intermediate entity as a third relationship.

The `CFFPartDisp` entity could look like this:

```
public class CFFPartDisp
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int CFFPartID { get; set; }
    public CFFPart CFFPart { get; set; }

    public int DispID { get; set; }
    public Disp Disp { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Expert> Experts { get; set; }
}
```

The `CFFPart` and `Disp` entities would need collections refering to `CFFPartDisp`:

```
public class CFFPart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CFFPartDisp> CFFPartDisps { get; set; }
}

public class Disp
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CFFPartDisp> CFFPartDisps { get; set; }
}
```

And `Expert` needs a collection of `CFFPartDisp` as well to establish the many-to-many relationship between `CFFPartDisp` and `Expert`:

```
public class Expert
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CFFPartDisp> CFFPartDisps { get; set; }
}
```

Using these entities you can create the three relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CFFPartDisp>()
    .HasRequired(cpd => cpd.CFFPart)
    .WithMany(cp => cp.CFFPartDisps)
    .HasForeignKey(cpd => cpd.CFFPartID);

modelBuilder.Entity<CFFPartDisp>()
    .HasRequired(cpd => cpd.Disp)
    .WithMany(cp => cp.CFFPartDisps)
    .HasForeignKey(cpd => cpd.DispID);

modelBuilder.Entity<CFFPartDisp>()
    .HasMany(cpd => cpd.Experts)
    .WithMany(e => e.CFFPartDisps)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("CFFPartDispID");
        m.MapRightKey("ExpertID");
        m.ToTable("CFFpartDisPExpert");
    });
```